# How Can I Prevent my SVG Shape From Sticking to the Bottom in IE 11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I am trying to create simple slash-shape for the front page of a website and having some trouble.

I finally managed to get a reasonable result (still not happy with the responsiveness), but when running in IE 11 the slash shape extends to the bottom of the page and covers everything below it.

Here is the code:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8fkxp1w/)

**HTML**

```
        <title>title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
  <body>
      <div id="main">
          <div id="welcomediv">
                <img src="img/mainlogo.png"/>
          </div>

          <div class="splash" id="p1">
              </div>


          <div class="splash">
               <svg id="ting" width="100%" viewBox="0 10 200 10">
                    <polygon id="arrow" points="0,30 0,500 250,500 250,-80" >
                    </polygon>
                </svg>                
          </div>


          <div class="splash" id="p2">  
          </div>    

      <div class="splash" id="p3">    
      </div>    
  </div>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#main {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.splash {
     height: 100vh;
     width: 100vw;
    float: left;
 }

#p1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
     background: black;
    background-image: url(img/bgic-fd.png);
    background-size: cover;
}

#p2 {
    background: black;
}

#p3 {
    z-index: 500;
    background: green;
}
#ting {

    position: absolute;
    top:25vh;

    height: 150vh;
}

#arrow {
    fill: #fec44a;
}

#welcomediv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50vw;
    top: 150px;
    margin-left: -15vw;
    z-index: 50;
    width: 30vw;
}

#welcomediv img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This works as expected in every other browser I've tried (Chrome Opera Firefox), but in IE 11 the yellow "#arrow" shape covers p2 and p3.

If anyone knows what is going on here I would really appreciate some guidance, thanks!